# Variable_scope runtime error when creating keras custom layer using tensorflow hub models and tensorflow 2.0 as backend

Tags: keras, scope, keras-layer, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to use the pretrained [tf-hub elmo model](https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2) by integrating it into a keras layer.

Keras Layer:

```
class ElmoEmbeddingLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ElmoEmbeddingLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.dimensions = 1024
        self.trainable = True
        self.elmo = None

    def build(self, input_shape):
        url = 'https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2'

        self.elmo = hub.Module(url)
        self._trainable_weights += trainable_variables(
            scope="^{}_module/.*".format(self.name))
        super(ElmoEmbeddingLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        result = self.elmo(
            x,
            signature="default",
            as_dict=True)["elmo"]
        return result

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0], self.dimensions
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Google Drive/Licenta/Gemini/Emotion Analysis/nn/trainer/model.py", line 170, in <module>
    validation_steps=validation_dataset.size())
  File "D:/Google Drive/Licenta/Gemini/Emotion Analysis/nn/trainer/model.py", line 79, in train_gpu
    model = build_model(self.config, self.embeddings, self.sequence_len, self.out_classes, summary=True)
  File "D:\Google Drive\Licenta\Gemini\Emotion Analysis\nn\architectures\models.py", line 8, in build_model
    return my_model(embeddings, config, sequence_length, out_classes, summary)
  File "D:\Google Drive\Licenta\Gemini\Emotion Analysis\nn\architectures\models.py", line 66, in my_model
    inputs, embedding = resolve_inputs(embeddings, sequence_length, model_config, input_type)
  File "D:\Google Drive\Licenta\Gemini\Emotion Analysis\nn\architectures\models.py", line 19, in resolve_inputs
    return elmo_input(model_conf)
  File "D:\Google Drive\Licenta\Gemini\Emotion Analysis\nn\architectures\models.py", line 58, in elmo_input
    embedding = ElmoEmbeddingLayer()(input_text)
  File "D:\Apps\Anaconda\envs\tf2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 616, in __call__
    self._maybe_build(inputs)
  File "D:\Apps\Anaconda\envs\tf2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1966, in _maybe_build
    self.build(input_shapes)
  File "D:\Google Drive\Licenta\Gemini\Emotion Analysis\nn\architectures\custom_layers.py", line 21, in build
    self.elmo = hub.Module(url)
  File "D:\Apps\Anaconda\envs\tf2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\module.py", line 156, in __init__
    abs_state_scope = _try_get_state_scope(name, mark_name_scope_used=False)
  File "D:\Apps\Anaconda\envs\tf2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\module.py", line 389, in _try_get_state_scope
    "name_scope was already taken." % abs_state_scope)
RuntimeError: variable_scope module/ was unused but the corresponding name_scope was already taken.
```

It seems to be due to the eager execution behaviour. If I disable eager execution I have to surround the model.fit function within a tensorflow session and initialize the variables by using `sess.run(global_variables_initializer())` to avoid the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Google Drive/Licenta/Gemini/Emotion Analysis/nn/trainer/model.py", line 168, in <module>
    validation_steps=validation_dataset.size().eval(session=Session()))
  File "D:/Google Drive/Licenta/Gemini/Emotion Analysis/nn/trainer/model.py", line 90, in train_gpu
    class_weight=weighted)
  File "D:\Apps\Anaconda\envs\tf2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 643, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "D:\Apps\Anaconda\envs\tf2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 664, in fit
    steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
  File "D:\Apps\Anaconda\envs\tf2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 294, in model_iteration
    batch_outs = f(actual_inputs)
  File "D:\Apps\Anaconda\envs\tf2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 3353, in __call__
    run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
  File "D:\Apps\Anaconda\envs\tf2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1458, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Failed precondition: Error while reading resource variable module/bilm/RNN_0/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell1/rnn/lstm_cell/bias from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/module/bilm/RNN_0/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell1/rnn/lstm_cell/bias/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
     [[{{node elmo_embedding_layer/module_apply_default/bilm/RNN_0/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell1/rnn/lstm_cell/bias/Read/ReadVariableOp}}]]
  (1) Failed precondition: Error while reading resource variable module/bilm/RNN_0/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell1/rnn/lstm_cell/bias from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/module/bilm/RNN_0/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell1/rnn/lstm_cell/bias/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
     [[{{node elmo_embedding_layer/module_apply_default/bilm/RNN_0/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell1/rnn/lstm_cell/bias/Read/ReadVariableOp}}]]
     [[metrics/f1_micro/Identity/_223]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

My solution:

```
with Session() as sess:
    sess.run(global_variables_initializer())
    history = model.fit(self.train_data.repeat(),
                        epochs=self.config['epochs'],
                        validation_data=self.validation_data.repeat(),
                        steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
                        validation_steps=validation_steps,
                        callbacks=self.__callbacks(monitor_metric),
                        class_weight=weighted)
```

The main question is if there is another way to use elmo tf-hub module in a keras custom layer and train my model. Another question is if my current solution is not affecting the training performances or give the OOM GPU error (I get the OOM error after a few epochs with a higher batch size, which I've found to be related to sessions not closed or memory leaks).

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your model in Session() field, you will also have to wrap all another code that uses your model in Session() field. It takes a lot times and efforts. I have another way to deal with it: 
firstly, create a elmo module, add a session to keras:

```
   elmo_model = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/3", trainable=True, 
   name='elmo_module')
   sess = tf.Session()
   sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
   sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
   K.set_session(sess)
```

Instead of create elmo module directly in your ElmoEmbeddinglayer

```
  self.elmo = hub.Module(url)
  self._trainable_weights += trainable_variables(
            scope="^{}_module/.*".format(self.name))
```

You can do the following, i think it works normally!

```
  self.elmo = elmo_model
  self._trainable_weights += trainable_variables(
            scope="^elmo_module/.*")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution that I used in my case:

That thing happened to me while I was using a separated python script to create the module.

To solve it I passed the tf.Session() in the main script to the tf.keras.backend in the other script by creating an entry point to pass it before calling the Layer.**init**

Example:

Main file:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
from ModuleFile import ModuleLayer

def __main__():
  init_args = [...]
  input = ...
  sess= tf.keras.backend.get_session()
  Module_layer.__init_session___(sess)
  module_layer = ModuleLayer(init_args)(input)
```

Module file:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

class ModuleLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

  @staticmethod
  def __init_session__(session):
    tf.keras.backend.set_session(session)

  def __init__(*args):
  ...
```

Hope that helps :)